# Is there a way to retrieve Google Map Longitude & Latitude from Addresses in Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-sheets, geotagging

I am currently working with a data listing and one of my columns of data is an address of the listing. I plan on plotting each of my addresses on a Google Map, but I would like to avoid having to manually paste the address into Google to obtain the parameters I need which are.

- Longitude
- Latitude

My excel sheet (Or I have it in Google Docs spreadsheet) contains about 3000 addresses. So I was hoping that there is someway to try and automatically get these extra column data so I can import into my backend.

I am going to be importing a CSV file into my database (As I have set up the long and lat's as custom fields that will be imported) so I need the final values as columns in my excel sheet. I have attached an example.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue ? how to add the gadget thi sgadget is depricated.any other alternative for that.

Comment: @Narasimha: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22581585/114029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this blog post](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2008/11/geocoding-with-google-spreadsheets-and.html) by Pamela Fox.  It is fairly old, but worked the last time I tried it.   It is limited to 100 entries of a spreadsheet at at time, but isn't too hard to run multiple times.

Comment: Funny, I just found that before you posted...I was just coming back here to post that exact answer...thanks!

Comment: As ScottYoumans' answer suggested, this suggestion no longer works :(

Answer (score 2):

I was using the good ol' Google Spreadsheet Gadget but [they were deprecated](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2791335).

Recently I saw that one of my old blog posts stopped showing a Google Map that was integrated with it.

A new search revealed this awesome project at GitHub called [geo-googledocs](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs):

> Tools to integrate MapBox with Google Docs 
>   http://mapbox.com/blog/mapping-google-doc-spreadsheet/

It does the job beautifully! You can see it working on [this spreadsheet](http://www.leniel.net/2009/06/astar-pathfinding-search-csharp-part-2.html) I updated right now for that old blog post I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The answers relating to Google spreadsheets are obsolete now.

I used this site which works well: http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.U_YD8x_8aYN

Answer (score 1):

Google Spreadsheet gadgets, like the one pointed to by [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip)'s answer, will soon be disabled.

Stephen Morse's [Batch Conversions of Address to Latitude/Longitude](http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlonbatch.html) page allows for copy-and-paste conversion via Yahoo.

Comment: Damn, apparently MapQuest doesn't allow you to confine your addresses to a certain country. Or at least not the way that this solution processes the supplied data...

Answer (score 0):

You can geocode addresses directly in Google Spreadsheets using the free [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com) add-on.  It allows for you to do all sorts of lightweight GIS tasks and create maps without writing a bunch of code.

After you install the add-on, try this:

```
=GEO_GEOCODE(A1:A10)
```

That should return the list of lat/lng's that you're looking for.